# Why can't I log into my SO account?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, openid, login

My StackOverflow account is associated with this Meta one.  When I log into Meta with the OpenID associated with my Google account, it works fine.  In fact, I can see my SO account on the related accounts page.  However, I logged out of SO today and now when I try to log back in with my Google OpenID, it doesn't work.  I ended up creating a new account that I log into when I try to use my Google OpenID and I can't figure out how I can access my original one.  I tried clearing my cache and switching browsers but to no avail.  When I try to directly paste my OpenID URL from the Meta account to the SO login page, it brings me to a Google Accounts page saying "The page you requested invalid." Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is that you didn't use your gmail as your openid. I will e-mail you your openid (to the e-mail address listed on the SO account).

Also; gmail openid is site-specific, so copy/paste between sites won't work anyway.

When you get back in, you might want to add your gmail as an alternative openid, to save this confusion in the future and to act as a backup in case your original provider goes offline at any point.

Also - let me know if you need any duplicate accounts merging / deleting because of this (stating which accounts).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply and especially for the fix!